# Need to merge git branch hotfix into main and dev but GitHub says there is no difference between hotfix and dev (there clearly is)

Tags: git, github, git-branch, branching-and-merging, hotfix

Dev is based off main; it is a work in progress for a new release, so it has much different code than main. I had to do a quick bugfix on the current version of my software, so I created a hotfix branch directly from main, then merged it back into main, no problem. Now, I need that hotfix in dev and my working branch from dev as well. When I try to merge the hotfix into either of these branches GitHub says:

> "There isn’t anything to compare. dev is up to date with all commits from hotfix. Try switching the base for your comparison."

I know, in fact, the changes in hotfix are not in dev. This is wasting so much of my time, please help.

Comment: what does 'git status' show for hotfix? What does 'git log --stat' show for hotfix and dev?

Comment: $ git status
On branch hotfix
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/hotfix'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: $ git log --stat
This shows many commits on both branches. What should I be looking for here?

Comment: the top commit for a branch is always the HEAD for that branch. Which file do you think should have changes in hotfix that aren't in dev? when you switch between those branches (git checkout <branch>) do you see the changes in that file in one branch and not in the other?

Comment: Also a screen shot of a git log --stat (for both branches) will be more useful for troubleshooting.

Comment: @opike HEAD is a pointer to the currently checked out commit or branch. It is not necessarily the tip of a branch.

Comment: There are several files with changes in hotfix that aren't in dev. Yes, the differences can be seen in VS when I switch between the branches. Also interesting to note, when I switch the base to hotfix and compare dev (gitHub), it does show the changes. Just not the other way around with dev as the base (which is what I need). I'll see if I can get a screenshot without too much sensitive info

Comment: Could it be that dev actually contains the more recent changes and that it already contains the changes from hotfix, but something was commited on top of it? What happens if you create a copy of hotfix and try to merge dev into the copy? Also, instead of doing a merge, you could also try to cherry-pick the commits over from hotfix to dev that you think contain the changes that are in hotfix but not yet in dev.